# If else condition to check if count has incremented

Tags: awk

I have a awk command:

```
awk '/a|b|c/{sum+=1} {if($NF=="e" && sum) count++} END {print sum, count}' file
```

so assume we apply this to a file `letter`:

```
a e
b d
c e
c f
d e
```

This means `sum` should be 4, and `count` should be 2 since last column is `e` for 2 rows that matches the pattern.

But I'm getting `4 3` instead, I think it may be reading $NF=e only, but unsure of how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `count` variable is incremented whenever the last column is the letter `e` and your `sum` variable is non-zero.  Your `sum` variable will be non-zero as soon as `sum+=1` is executed, which is the first thing that happens when your code sees the first line of input, given your example text.  You then have `e` in the second column three times.

If you want to increment `sum` when the line matches `a|b|c` and `count` when the line's last column additionally is `e`:

```bsh
awk '/a|b|c/ { ++sum; if ($NF == "e") count++ } END { print sum+0, count+0 }' file
```

The `+0` in the `END` block makes sure that the output will be `0` rather than empty if a counter has not been incremented at all.

Comment: Thank you! Can I possibly do ```!++sum``` for patterns that did not match?

Comment: @Hewitt I'm not quite sure what you mean. The number of lines that does not match your `a|b|c` pattern will be `NR - sum` (in the `END` block).

Comment: I see. So if I'd like  to get non-matches and ```$NF=="e"```, how should I change it? since ```++sum``` is for matches.

Comment: @Hewitt Isn't that what `count` is counting. It seems that `count` is counting lines that has both `e` in the last column and that matches `a|b|c`.  What is it that you want to count now?  Is it simply `NR - count` then? What do you mean by "a match"?  You have two conditions.

Comment: I think because ```NR-sum``` only gives you number of rows that don't match, but I'd like to apply the ```if($NF=="e")``` statement onto the rows in ```NR-sum```. Is there a possible way to do it without applying another ```!~``` to my regex?

Comment: @Hewitt I'm trying _very hard_ to understand what your new requirements are. Is it to count the number of times `e` occurs in the last column without `a|b|c` matching the line? Would you still need to count the number of times `a|b|c` matched? Would you still need to count the number of time the last column was `e` with `a|b|c` matching? Recall that I can't read your mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128555/discussion-between-hewitt-and-kusalananda).

Comment: @Hewitt [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum. if you have requirements you didn't include in this question then simply ask a new followup question, don't add or modify requirements in comments.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, fixed.